# Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference

Tags: regex, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to remove some text from a listbox and i keep getting this error.

```
Error   1   Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.
```

Here's the code that's causing the error.

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(Match.ToString.Replace("color: 0863BB;", "").Replace("</span>", "").Replace(">", "").Replace("""", ""))
```

This is my full code below. 
I have no idea what i am doing wrong please help.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Regex As New Regex("color: 0863BB;" & Chr(34) & ">(.*?)</span></span>")
    Dim Matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(RichTextBox1.Text)

    For Each Match As Match In Matches

        ListBox1.Items.Add(Match.ToString)

    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'RichTextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.DocumentText

End Sub

Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Match.ToString.Replace("color: 0863BB;", "").Replace("</span>", "").Replace(">", "").Replace("""", ""))
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If ListBox1.Items.Contains("<span>") Then

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    '  (Match.ToString.Replace("color: 0863BB;", "").Replace("</span>", "").Replace(">", "").Replace("""", ""))
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is complaining about `Match.ToString`. `ToString` is an instance method, but `Match` is a type.